Add a pattern on a circos heatmap
I wrote a script to draw a circle heatmap using the package circlize from R. Below is the picture of the plot.

I would like to add some pattern for specific value (stripped for "DeH" and circle for "DuN".
What is the best way to do that ?
Please find below my data (Three dataframes for the different section of the heatmap) and my script.
The first dataframe corresponds to the corresponding chr of each genes.
The second dataframe corresponds to the first category of sample with possible different type of variant for each gene (De, DeH, Du, DuN).
The third dataframe corresponds to the second category of sample with possible different type of variant for each gene (De, DeH, Du, DuN).
########### Library ###########

library(circlize)
library(gridpattern)
library(grid)

########### Data ###########

tab_heatmap = structure(list(bb = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", 
                      "chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr2", "chr2", "chr2", "chr2", "chr2", 
                      "chr3", "chr3", "chr3", "chr3", "chr3", "chr3", "chr3", "chr3", 
                      "chr3", "chr5", "chr5", "chr5", "chr6", "chr7", "chr7", "chr7", 
                      "chr7", "chr8", "chr9", "chr9", "chr10", "chr11", "chr13", "chr14", 
                      "chr15", "chr15", "chr15", "chr15", "chr15", "chr15", "chr16", 
                      "chr16", "chr16", "chr16", "chr16", "chr16", "chr16", "chr16", 
                      "chr16", "chr16", "chr17", "chr17", "chr17", "chr18", "chr18", 
                      "chr19", "chr19", "chr20", "chr20", "chr20", "chr20", "chr21", 
                      "chr22", "chr22", "chr22", "chr22", "chr22", "chr22", "chr22", 
                      "chrX", "chrX", "chrX", "chrX")),
                 row.names = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4", "Gene5", "Gene6", "Gene7", "Gene8", "Gene9", 
                               "Gene10", "Gene11", "Gene12", "Gene13", "Gene14", "Gene15", "Genes16", 
                               "Gene17", "Gene18", "Gene19", "Gene20", "Gene21", "Gene22", "Gene23", 
                               "Gene24", "Gene25", "Gene26", "Gene27", "Gene28", "Gene29", "Gene30", 
                               "Gene31", "Gene32", "Gene33", "Gene34", "Gene35", "Gene36", "Gene37", 
                               "Gene38", "Gene39", "Gene40", "Gene41", "Gene42", "Gene43", "Gene44", 
                               "Gene45", "Gene46", "Gene47", "Gene48", "Gene49", "Gene50", "Gene51", 
                               "Gene52", "Gene53", "Gene54", "Gene55", "Gene56", "Gene57", "Gene58", 
                               "Gene59", "Gene60", "Gene61", "Gene62", "Gene63", "Gene64", "Gene65", 
                               "Gene66", "Gene67", "Gene68", "Gene69", "Gene70", "Gene71", "Gene72", 
                               "Gene73", "Gene74", "Gene75", "Gene76"), class = "data.frame")


                                                                                        
tab_heatmap_P = structure(list(A2 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                                        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "DeH", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                                        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                                        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                                        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                                        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                                        "0", "0", "0", "0"),
                               B5 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                                      "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                                      "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                                      "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                                      "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "De", 
                                      "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                                      "0", "0", "0", "0", "0")), class = "data.frame", 
                          row.names = c("Gene1","Gene4", "Gene5",  "Gene6", "Gene7","Gene8", "Gene9", "Gene10", 
                                        "Gene11", "Gene12", "Gene13", "Gene14",  "Gene15", "Gene16",  "Gene16", "Gene17", 
                                        "Gene18", "Gene19", "Gene20", "Gene21", "Gene22", "Gene23",  "Gene24", "Gene25", 
                                        "Gene26", "Gene27", "Gene28", "Gene29", "Gene30", "Gene31", "Gene32", "Gene33", "Gene34", 
                                        "Gene35", "Gene36", "Gene37", "Gene38",  "Gene39", "Gene40", "Gene41", "Gene42", "Gene43", "Gene44", 
                                        "Gene45", "Gene46",  "Gene47", "Gene48",  "Gene49", "Gene50",  "Gene51", "Gene52", "Gene53", "Gene54", 
                                        "Gene55", "Gene56",   "Gene57", "Gene58","Gene59", "Gene60",  "Gene61", "Gene62", "Gene63", "Gene64",
                                        "Gene65", "Gene66", "Gene67", "Gene68", "Gene69", "Gene70",  "Gene71", "Gene72", "Gene73", "Gene73", 
                                        "Gene74", "Gene75", "Gene76"))

tab_heatmap_R = structure(list(V1 = c("0", "0", "De", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                                       "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                                       "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                                       "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                                       "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                                       "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                                       "0", "0", "0"),  
                V4 = c("0", "0", "0", "Du", "DuN", 
                      "Du", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                       "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                         "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                       "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
                    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), 
                 V8 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "Du", "0", "0", "0", "0"), 
                 V10 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                         "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                         "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                         "0", "De", "De", "De", "De", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                         "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                         "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
                        "0", "0", "0")), class = "data.frame", 
                row.names = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4", "Gene5", 
                "Gene6", "Gene7", "Gene8", "Gene9", "Gene10", "Gene11", "Gene12","Gene13", "Gene14", "Gene15",
                "Gene16", "Gene17", "Gene18", "Gene19", "Gene20", "Gene21", "Gene22", "Gene23", "Gene24", "Gene25",
                "Gene26", "Gene27", "Gene28", "Gene29", "Gene30", "Gene31", "Gene32", "Gene33", "Gene34", "Gene35",
                "Gene36", "Gene37", "Gene38", "Gene39", "Gene40", "Gene41", "Gene42", "Gene43", "Gene44", "Gene45", "Gene46",
                "Gene47", "Gene48", "Gene49", "Gene50", "Gene51", "Gene52", "Gene53", "Gene54", "Gene55", "Gene56", "Gene57",
                "Gene58", "Gene59", "Gene60", "Gene61", "Gene62", "Gene63", "Gene64", "Gene65", "Gene66", "Gene67", "Gene68",
                "Gene69", "Gene70", "Gene71", "Gene72", "Gene73", "Gene74", "Gene75", "Gene76")) 


# Color

col_fun_type = c("De" = "red", "DeH"= "red", "Du" = "blue","DuN" = "blue", "DuM"="skyblue", "0"="grey90")
col_fun_chr=c("chr1"="black", "chr2"="grey", "chr3"="black", "chr4"="grey", "chr5"="black", "chr6"="grey","chr7"="black", "chr8"="grey", "chr9"="black", 
              "chr10"="grey", "chr11"="black", "chr12"="grey", "chr13"="black", "chr14"="grey", "chr15"="black", "chr16"="grey", "chr17"="black", 
              "chr18"="grey", "chr19"="black", "chr20"="grey", "chr21"="black", "chr22"="grey", "chrX"="black")

# Gap for heatmap

split = tab_heatmap$bb

# Plot



pdf("circostest.pdf", height = 40, width=40)
circos.clear()

circos.par(gap.after = gap_chr)

circos.heatmap(tab_heatmap, split=split, col = col_fun_chr, track.height = 0.05, cell.border=FALSE,cluster = FALSE, na.col="white", rownames.side = "inside",rownames.cex = 3)

circos.track(track.index = get.current.track.index(), panel.fun = function(x, y) {
  circos.text(CELL_META$xcenter, CELL_META$cell.ylim[2] + convert_y(2, "mm"), 
              paste0( CELL_META$sector.index),
              facing = "bending.inside", cex = 2,
              adj = c(0.5, 0), niceFacing = TRUE)
}, bg.border = NA)

circos.heatmap(tab_heatmap_P, col=col_fun_type, split=split, track.height = 0.03, cluster = FALSE,  na.col = "white", bg.border =  "white", cell.border="white")

circos.track(track.index = get.current.track.index(), panel.fun = function(x, y) {
  if(CELL_META$sector.numeric.index == 21) { # the last sector
    circos.rect(CELL_META$cell.xlim[2] + convert_x(1, "mm"), 0,
                CELL_META$cell.xlim[2] + convert_x(10, "mm"), ncol(tab_heatmap_P),
                col = "grey", border = NA)
    circos.text(CELL_META$cell.xlim[2] + convert_x(3, "mm"), 2.5,
                "P", cex = 2, facing = "clockwise")
  }
}, bg.border = NA)

circos.heatmap(tab_heatmap_R, col=col_fun_type, split=split, track.height = 0.13, cluster = FALSE,  na.col = "white", bg.border =  "white", cell.border="white")

circos.track(track.index = get.current.track.index(), panel.fun = function(x, y) {
  if(CELL_META$sector.numeric.index == 21) { # the last sector
    circos.rect(CELL_META$cell.xlim[2] + convert_x(1, "mm"), 0,
                CELL_META$cell.xlim[2] + convert_x(10, "mm"), ncol(tab_heatmap_R),
                col = "grey", border = NA)
    circos.text(CELL_META$cell.xlim[2] + convert_x(3, "mm"), 2.5,
                "R", cex = 2, facing = "clockwise")
  }
}, bg.border = NA)



dev.off()





